# Localstack (AWS) credential failure on java lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, java-17, localstack

The purpose of this lambda is insert a bucket content on a kinesis data stream, here is the code:

```
package productor;

import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.*;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.*;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.PutRecordRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.PutRecordResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsBasicCredentials;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.StaticCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.ResponseInputStream;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.SdkBytes;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import java.util.*;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

import java.io.*;

import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectResponse;

public class Productor implements RequestHandler<Map<String,String>, String>{
    static List<String> status_code = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public static Map<String, Object> conexion() {
        //diccionario con conexiones
        Map<String, Object> conexiones = new HashMap<>();

        //Crear clientes de S3
        try {
            String accessKey = "dummy";
            String secretKey = "dummy";
            
            // Crea las credenciales básicas
            AwsBasicCredentials awsCredentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey, secretKey);
            // Crear proveedor de credenciales estáticas
            StaticCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCredentials);
            
            S3Client s3_client = S3Client.builder().region(Region.US_EAST_1).credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();           
            KinesisClient kinesis_client = KinesisClient.builder().region(Region.US_EAST_1).credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
            
            conexiones.put("s3_client", s3_client);
            conexiones.put("kinesis_client", kinesis_client);
            status_code.add("Funcion_conexion.conexion_creada");
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            status_code.add("Funcion_conexion." + e.getMessage());
        }
        return conexiones;
    }
    
    public static String objeto_fichero(Map<String, Object> localstack) {
        String texto = "None";
        
        try {
            S3Client s3Client = (S3Client) localstack.get("s3_client");
            
            //OLD
            //ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> objeto_bucket1 = s3Client.getObject(b -> b.bucket(bucket_name).key(file));
            
            //Generar peticion a localstack y capturar respuesta
            GetObjectRequest solicitud_fichero = GetObjectRequest.builder().bucket("bucket1").key("contenido.txt").build();
            ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> fichero = s3Client.getObject(solicitud_fichero);
            
            // Usar BufferedReader para leer el contenido de la respuesta
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fichero));
            StringBuilder textoBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                textoBuilder.append(line);
            }
            texto = textoBuilder.toString();
            status_code.add("Funcion_fichero.objeto_extraido");
            
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            status_code.add("Funcion_fichero." + e.getMessage());
        }
        return texto;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings({ "finally", "unused" })
    public static List<String> subida_kinesis(Map<String, Object> localstack, String objeto) {
        try {
            KinesisClient kinesisClient = (KinesisClient) localstack.get("kinesis_client");
            String streamName = "MiFlujoDeDatos";
            
            //generar peticion y solicitar input al server
            PutRecordRequest solicitud_input = PutRecordRequest.builder().streamName(streamName).data(SdkBytes.fromUtf8String(objeto)).partitionKey("Lorem").build();
            PutRecordResponse response = kinesisClient.putRecord(solicitud_input);
            status_code.add("Funcion_kinesis.objeto_guardado");
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            status_code.add("Funcion_kinesis." + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            return status_code;
        }

    }
    
    public String handleRequest(Map<String,String> event, Context context) {
        return subida_kinesis(conexion(),objeto_fichero(conexion())).toString();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(subida_kinesis(conexion(),objeto_fichero(conexion())));
    }

}
```

I create the lambda in aws cli:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 lambda create-function --function-name Productor --runtime java17 --handler productor.Productor::handleRequest --role arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/RolLambda --zip-file fileb://./Productor-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

And this is the json output:

```
"[Funcion_conexion.conexion_creada, Funcion_conexion.conexion_creada, Funcion_fichero.The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: S4DR2KVRMDW7W3AE, Extended Request ID: IiQQx/+M8+j0Y8ZoCdVkxJ+wioZZDEQPIxeFkI/Vzqbx+Bb+71Q92T2kqdkh6NCKwFkx9K7LYdQ=), Funcion_kinesis.The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: Kinesis, Status Code: 400, Request ID: f7884fc7-2ff4-1f17-aa1f-7f28ff3fbe9f, Extended Request ID: i7Pr7W/hK6q8eisFtF7HkD7sN3C2QhEMvtmk01SHQx7i1LLt184Ua4EpC07Tuic+aL1otTF6hIw9VqnQ8uWhPRaf7g00TEVlx7+cIQJZ4xI=)]"
```

I cannot figure out whats wrong with the code, maybe credentials issue but I established that credentials in localstack using aws configure.
Any suggestions?
Thanks for reading

Comment: What does your credentials file look like?

Comment: You issue is your creds are invalid. See message "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records".  However, you do not need creds when writing a Lambda function and deploying it with the AWS Console. You can use Roles instead. See my response.

Answer (score 1):

WHen writing a Java Lambda function using the Java Lambda Runtime API, you do not need credentials as you do when you write a client app that uses the Java SDK.

Instead of using creds, when you deploy the Lambda function, you specify a role that has permission to invoke the AWS Services that the Lambda function uses. Create a role that has permission to invoke the AWS Services you want to invoke with your Lambda function and then reference that Role when you deploy the Lambda function with AWS Lambda Console.

To see a practial example that build a Lambda function using Java and as part of that, creates a role that the Lambda function uses, see this Lambda example in the [AWS Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html):

[Detect PPE in images with Amazon Rekognition using an AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/rekognition_example_cross_RekognitionPhotoAnalyzerPPE_section.html)